# Set CSV import default to UTF-8 in Calc

Tags: openoffice, encoding, import, csv, openoffice-calc

Every time I open a CSV (comma separated values) document in OpenOffice.org Calc I get a dialog with CSV preferences.

The current default character set is "Eastern Europe (ISO-8859-2)".

I would like "UTF-8" to be selected by default instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem was in **LC_** settings in my system. It was set to:

```
LANG="cs_CZ"
```

which probably defaults to *ISO-8859-2*. After altering this to:

```
cat /etc/env.d/02locale
...
LANG="cs_CZ.UTF-8"
...

env-update && source /etc/profile
reboot # just to be sure
```

Everything is ok. CSV defaults to UTF-8.

Comment: http://forum.openoffice.cz/viewtopic.php?pid=4574#p4574 -> The same question in Czech (posted by me, answered by myself). Just to let Google know these questions are related.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is controlled by your Locale Settings.

For me CSV files default to UTF-8

In Tools > Options > Language Settings > Languages.

My Locale is set to default.
My Language is set to English (UK)

The Locale of the PC is English (UK)

Comment: I tried this too, but no luck. Locale setting, User interface, Default languages for documents - Western. All set to English (UK).

Comment: I am running OOo 3.1.1 on Ubuntu Linux. I do not know if that makes a difference. Perhaps you are on an older version or you have found a bug!

Comment: I am running OO-3.2.0 on Gentoo. It's strange that OO honors LC_ settings instead it's own settings. Anyway, I posted solution which worked for me. Thanks for your time Richard.